# How to make Firefox button respect padding?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, padding

For some reason Firefox `button` elements don't seem to respect the CSS `padding` declarations, even if you make them `display: block`.

See this JSFiddle in Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/DgeQ6/

Notice how the padding works in Chrome but not in Firefox. How do I get Firefox to pay attention to `padding` in `button` elements?

Here's a screenshot of how it looks on Firefox on my machine:

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s217/sh/dc349236-9a7e-46f2-ae77-3a7581fa78c1/ea90d1f4a880ba64257fdd744b9fabcf

The padding should be 20px but it's not affected.

Comment: Upgrade your Firefox. It's working fine...

Comment: I'm using Firefox 22...

Comment: I'm using Firefox 20 & it looks perfectly fine

Comment: Seems good on firefox 22. Can you please post images describing the behaviour?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 22 and the OP is correct. Try changing the padding size and it always remains the same for Firefox (Safari and Chrome works).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit should go to Boris below but you need to use -moz-appearance:none to override the OS level button stylings. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DgeQ6/8/.

HTML

```
<button class="btn-large">Hello</button>
```

CSS

```
.btn-large {
    padding: 100px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

It should also be noted that Twitter Bootstrap appears to achieve the same effect for their buttons in Firefox just by having a "border-radius" styling along with padding.

Answer (score 2):

Padding by itself doesn't work on Mac because the Mac native-themed look for buttons overrides the padding.  On Windows it works just fine, for example.  I can't recall what the behavior is on Linux offhand.

The safest way to deal with this is to set `-moz-appearance: none` if you want to drop the native-themed look.

Comment: Thanks Boris for the clarification. I updated my answer above and gave you reps. Do you happen to understand why using border-radius:0 in conjunction with padding also achieves the same effect for Firefox?

Comment: @MinhNguyen Sure.  Styling the border in a way that's not the default OS style also drops native theming, so it's just a weird way to achieve the effect of `-moz-appearance: none`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It looks like this in my firefox.